# spring thymeleaf error EL1008E Property or field cannot be found on object of type 'LiveDataController$LiveDataSet' maybe not public or not valid?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

im using thymeleaf to pass index.html to model attribute containing LiveDataSet Class. but i keep encountering this error.

```
    ***org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'LiveDataSet' cannot be found on object of type 'com.ex.excom.controller.LiveDataController$LiveDataSet' - maybe not public or not valid?***
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:217)
PropertyOrFieldReference.java:217
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104)
PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:51)
PropertyOrFieldReference.java:51
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:406)
PropertyOrFieldReference.java:406
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:90)
CompoundExpression.java:90
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:109)
SpelNodeImpl.java:109
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:328)
SpelExpression.java:328
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:263)
SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:263
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166)
VariableExpression.java:166
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66)
SimpleExpression.java:66
```

LiveDataController

```
@RestController
@Controller
public class LiveDataController extends BaseController
{
    public class LiveDataSet
    {

        String getActive;
        String getApparent;
        String getCurrent;
        String getEnergy;
    }
    public LiveDataSet getLiveDatas(){    
         ...
        LiveDataSet liveDatas = new LiveDataSet();

        liveDatas.getCurrent = "1234"
        liveDatas.getEnergy = "92.1"
        ...
        return liveDatas
    }
}
```

IndexController

```
@RequestMapping("/")
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')")
public String index(Model model, HttpSession session)
{

    LiveDataSet liveData = liveDataController.getLiveDatas();
    Optional<LiveDataSet> listOptLiveData = Optional.of(liveData);
    listOptLiveData.ifPresent(LiveDataSet -> model.addAttribute("liveData", liveData));     
    return "index";
}
```

index.html

```
<tr th:each="row : ${liveData}">
    <td th:text="${row.LiveDataSet}"></td>      
</tr>
```

how i can handle this error.. data does exist, but i can even see the data in the view.
Thank you for reading this.

Comment: [[${liveData}]] this prints like this.
-> com.ex.excom.controller.LiveDataController$LiveDataSet@18b9fc7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[${liveData}]]

```
public class LiveDataSet
{

    String getActive; -> dActive;
    String getApparent; -> dApparent;
    String getCurrent; -> dCurrent;
    String getEnergy; -> dEnergy
}
```

the problem is, variable naming. if i declare variable get + Active , it returns get, property so this cause java variable detect malfunction so i changed variable names and it safely returns value.

Answer (score 0):

`liveData` that you are sending to view is an instance of `LiveDataSet`. In the view you are accessing it as `${row.LiveDataSet}`. It doesn't make sense. There isn't any `LiveDataSet` field in your `LiveDataSet`! That's why you are getting this error.

Comment: hi @Minar  but i already tried to variate like [[${row.LiveDataSet.getActive}]], [[${row.getActive}]] and many ways but still doesn't work. moreover, can't accesible even in javascript  /*<![CDATA[*/ var liveData = [[${ liveData }]]; /*]]>*/

Answer (score 0):

You should access the attrs of the Object row (that is an instance of that LiveDataSet i belive)

```
<thead>
<tr>
<td>Col1</td>
<td>Col2</td>
<td>Col3</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr th:each="row : ${liveData}">
        <td th:text="${row.attr1}"></td>
        <td th:text="${row.attr2}"></td>      
        <td th:text="${row.attr3}"></td>            
    </tr>
</tbdoy>
```

Comment: Hello Pablo  i've already tried so many times like this. but it still doesn't work Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue and in the long run i realised i didn't have a getter/setter for them in their parent class (another downside of not using lombok). After the getter setter and renaming, it worked. Perhaps you should look into that.